# Testing for significant differences after discarding a potential confounding factor

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions

I'm looking for a statistical test that could be appropriate for the following case:

I have a continuous variable (Y) and two categorical explanatory variables (A and B). There are significant differences in Y between the distinct categories of A and between the distinct categories of B. I'm particularly interested in variable A, which has two categories (A1 and A2). Basically I want to see whether the fact that A1 and A2 have significantly distinct distributions of Y values is not explained because A1 and A2 present distinct distributions of B categories (i.e., it may be that A1 is presents higher values for Y because it is enriched in those B categories that present higher values for Y).

Because I don't know the appropriate statistical test for this, I've done the following:

I have a total of 1000 datapoints, 100 are A1 and 990 are A2 (let's call them A1-datapoints and A2-datapoints).
For a series of iterations, I randomly sampled in each iteration 100 A2-datapoints, in a way that the randomly sampled A2-datapoints always have the same distribution of B categories than the 100 A1-datapoints.
Then, in each iteration, I checked whether there are differences in the distributions between A1-datapoints (which are always the same) and the randomly sampled subset of A2-datapoints with the Kolmogorov–Smirnov test (the data doesn't follow a normal distribution, so I can't use ANOVA).
After the series of iterations, I have one p-value from every iteration, and because <99% of p-values are below the significance level, I assume that A1 and A2 present distinct distributions of Y values with independence of the category B.

However, I guess there must be some statistical test that could work for my particular case and could allow me to reach the same conclusion in a more simple way. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Welcome to the site! So your question is basically: is the conditional distribution of Y conditioned on A, moderated (influenced) by B? Or in other words: what is the effect of A and B on the distribution of Y? Is this correct? If yes, why don't you simply regress Y on A and B with an interaction term A*B? If we assume that the coefficient of B in the DGP is zero, then it's independent of Y hence it doesn't affect it's distribution either. (Note that with OLS regression insignificant coefficients don't show independence, rather only mean-independence under the null.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, PaulG! Providing that in the OLS I obtain that A, B and A*B components are significant the three of them, my interpretation, correct me if I'm wrong please, would be that I can't discard the possibility that A explains Y because A interacts with B, and B could be the real explanatory variable. In such a case, would there be any way to explore whether the fraction of the variability of A that is not correlated with B also explains Y?

It could be that I'm not understanding how I should interpret OLS regression results